# How can I create a server where I can access it over the internet?

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I am trying to create a computer that has Ubuntu on it. I then want to be a able to access this computer over the internet (I can be somewhere else and "log-on" to be computer). I would prefer if I could connect through it using a program like remote desktop that is already on most computers. Thank you for your time and help!!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do? Do you want to set up a file server, or do you actually want a remote desktop server like Remote Desktop/Terminal Services on Windows?

Comment: He Said llike remote desktop. What is unclear about that? So he wants to access it like he's sitting at it.  Like he has logged on.  And obviously securely, over the internet. Couldn't be clearer. He even said remote desktop.. and if he didn't mean that then doesn't matter 'cos that's clearly what his question clearly says!

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu you'll have to install `openssh-server` and configure it to startup with the system. If you have a public IP address then assign it to the NIC; if you do not you'll have to use NAT on a router with port forwarding. Once you've done this you'll want to allow any firewalls between your gateway and the server to allow connections via ssh (port 22) to the Ubuntu machine.